# How to calculate the fourth order cumulant in higher order statistic using R?

Tags: r, statistics

Can anyone let me know how I can calculate the 4rth order cumulants using sliding window in R.

The sample data is like:

```
-644691181
-121187080
353422690
417492115
-504192375
420646272
-47480551
260350503
2151074145
1251550732
788874753
540183268
396739715
948170766
-1433091907
-148444555
-840182654
-893652578
-1738734435
-1431476210
24974246
93873803
-324033231
479813749
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I'll make an attempt. There's an `all.cumulants` function available in package [**moments**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moments/moments.pdf). Please read it before using this example.

```
require(moments)
all.cumulants(all.moments(x, order.max=4))
# [1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 7.663353e+17 3.842980e+25 8.177093e+34
```

all.cumulants takes moments of ordner n=0 to k as input. Since you require 4th order cumulants, I suspect you'll have to calculate raw moments upto 4th order and then compute `all.cumulants`. Does this sound right? If not, please leave a comment and I shall delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response.... Your answer is not the same what I am looking for, but now I have an idea on which I can proceed further based on your explanations :)

Comment: @Arun... Have you tried to calculate fourth order cumulants using sliding window, If not then kindly do me favor in that and help me out of this. I have no idea how to do this :( Thanking You in advance

Comment: you'll have to explain what you mean by 4th order cumulants "using sliding window" better, by *editing your original post*. Also show for the test example show us what you expect.

Comment: @Arun I have a problem statement which is like: "Calculate the fourth order cumulants using sliding window". I have 1st calculated the sliding window and output of this I am giving the input to calculate the fourth cumulant. Am I doing right? Now let me know what else you want to know with respect to my questions.Thank you for your kind responses

Comment: I've never used `cumulants`. I *already* told you unless you show me what output you expect for a test data, and/or how to calculate this using a `sliding window` (and what's the window size, btw?), there is *no way* for me to help you.

Comment: @Arun... Thanks for response. Can I have your email id please or you can send it my email id because I can't give the all the details of my questions over here due to lack of space.... hope you understand my problem.